# MongoDB Document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm learning MongoDb, below is my requirement , I would like to write a document out of it. Need your help on this.

Requirement : I have below tabels in my relation Db, now I would like to convert this to document:

1. Manager (id, name)
2. Technical Lead (id, name , manager_id) manager_id is the fk.
3. Development Lead (id,name, tech_lead_id) tech_lead_id is the fk.

How to convert this in Document.

Thanks,
Sudheer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using mongoexport command.
Here is an official document of this command:
[mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

This command supports exporting to CSV and JSON. You can convert your results into one of them and convert to other formats whatever you want using other languages (I personally use Python).

---

For your reference:

CSV:

mongoexport --db relation --collection manager --fields id,name --type=csv --out manager.csv

JSON:

mongoexport --db relation --collection manager --fields id,name --out manager.json

Comment: if I have use this to create a new document without using mongoexport, can I do , if so how do I refer with a unique id another table.

Comment: If you don't want to use mongoexport command, you can try doing it in your own programming language. I use Python with PyMongo, I know C# has a library too and you can try also. These libraries act as the client to query the database and get the results that you want. You can then export the results as you like.

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I understand that you would like to get a MongoDB database schema based on what it would like in a RDBMS.
First things first; DB schema design in MongoDB is not a straightforward conversion of RDBMS. Also, there are different factors you would consider when designing your DB schema in MongoDB as compared with a RDBMS DB schema design.
Having said that, I would take a stab at it to provide one way of doing it:

Manager :

```
{ _id : ObjectId("AAA"), name : "julie"}
```

Technical Lead :

```
{ _id : ObjectId("BBB"), name : "jack", manager : "julie"}
```

Development Lead :

```
{ _id : ObjectId("CCC"), name : "john", techLead : "jack"}
```

As you would see above, I have pre-joined the data with the names of 'manager' & 'techLead' and have not used an ObjectId. However, it could also have been with the _id like below :

Technical Lead :

```
{ _id : ObjectId("BBB"), name : "jack", manager : ObjectId("AAA")}
```

In MongoDB schema design, factors like cardinality (one-to-many, one-to-few, etc.) and data access patterns (frequently executed queries/updates) have to be considered while selecting whether you want to put a reference or denormalize and put the data. There is NO one correct way of doing it, all have their pros & cons. But, you could choose one design which is suited best for YOUR application requirements.

Below posts from Mongo gives really good explanation with examples: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1